# How to get around duplicates when inserting multiple values for many to many relationship - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Adding keywords to db.
I have 3 tables.

```
Articles
-ArticleID PK
-ArticleTitle
-ArticleBody

Keywords
-KeywordID PK
-Keyword UNIQUE

Keyword_Article
-KeywordID PK
-ArticleID
```

Trying to figure out how to update the Keyword tables as efficiently as possible.
All I have is SQLBUDDY to work with for now.

I have had success with

```
INSERT INTO Keywords (KeywordID, Keyword)
VALUES (NULL,'test');
INSERT INTO Keyword_Article (KeywordID, ArticleID)
VALUES ('LAST_INSERT_ID()','2222');
```

But when I run into a keyword that already exists this obviously does not work.
Im guessing a need an if/else/then or is there some other way that this should be done.
I have read about stored procedures which could help stop the second table from populating if the first one fails but I cant seem to get them to work in SQLBUDDY.

eg.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Keywords (KeywordID, Keyword)
VALUES (NULL,'test')
INSERT INTO Keyword_Article (KeywordID, ArticleID)
VALUES ('LAST_INSERT_ID()','2222');
COMMIT;
```

Keeps giving errors.

What is the best way to do this kind of multiple insert?

Comment: INSERT IGNORE INTO ?  should ignore duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Keywords (Keyword)
VALUES ('test')
INSERT INTO Keyword_Article (KeywordID, ArticleID)
VALUES ((SELECT KeywordID FROM Keywords WHERE Keyword = 'test'),'2222');
```

That will try to insert a new keyword, but ignore it if it already exists.  The second query will always find the KeywordID whether it is new or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
-- Forces Keyword to be unique
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Keywords_ndx ON Keywords(Keyword);
```

and then:

```
-- Inserts keyword into Keywords, failing silently if duplicated
INSERT IGNORE INTO `Keywords` (`Keyword`) VALUES ('test');

-- Retrieves that keyword's ID, be it newly inserted or duplicated.
INSERT IGNORE INTO Keyword_Article (KeywordID, ArticleID)
    SELECT KeywordID, 2222 FROM Keywords WHERE Keyword='test';
```

`Keyword_Article` has both fields as primary key. You declared only KeywordID as PK, but that way, you cannot have two articles with the same keyword, which seems strange and may lead to undesired behaviour.

Comment: Both answers worked but chose yours because of the extra info which saved me some head scratching :)

Comment: Sorry had to change chosen answer cuz on second look this solution did not work for me... still thanks for the extra info

Comment: No problem, don't worry. But what *extra info*? :-?